# Rails 3: validate REGEX fails if no value input

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I am using the following REGEX

```
VALID_WEBSITE_REGEX = /^(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,6}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/ix
```

to validate a website entry with this rule:

```
validates :website, length: { maximum: 150 }, format: { with: VALID_WEBSITE_REGEX }
```

(The 150 is arbitrary).

However, when I save / update the form I get a validation error "website is invalid". How do I ensure that the 'format' section of the validation rule is processed only if there is content to process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use allow_blank option for validation

```
:allow_blank => true
```

This option will let validation pass if the attribute’s value is blank?, like nil or an empty string for example.
read more:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#allow_blank

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the entire thing with the `?` operator, e.g.

```
VALID_WEBSITE_REGEX = /^((http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,6}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?)?$/ix
```

If you want to allow whitespace too, then add `\s*` on each end, e.g.

```
VALID_WEBSITE_REGEX = /^\s*((http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,6}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?)?\s*$/ix
```